# How can we know if two names which have the same referent have the same meaning or different meanings?

Tags: semantics

“A cute cat” and “a black cat” can have the same referent but have explicitly different meanings.

Then, how can we know if two proper nouns, especially names, which have the same referent have the same meaning or different meanings?

It’s really hard to know because dictionaries only tell us only if names are male or female but not about their meanings (not etymological meanings but literal meanings).

[image]

Comment: I seem to recall learning that names are considered to mean their referent; that is, they mean "The person picked out by [name]." In that case two names with the same referent have the same meaning. But I have no idea if that view is mainstream.

Comment: Meaning is determined by speakers and hearers, independently. If the hearer doesn't think two names with the same referent have the same meaning, they don't; and if they think they do, then they do. Get some data before drawing conclusions. Or define _meaning_ in a non-circular way.

Comment: Apart from etymological meaning (which may still be transparent – e.g., Lily, Rose, Rock), what meaning do you suppose a proper name could have, other than a reference to its referent? ‘James’ has no meaning independent of the person you’re referring to when you use that name.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet What about regnal names, pet names from a partner, full names spoken by a disciplining parent, nicknames from friends. Which name is used for a person could encode a distinct relationship with the person, even though they might all be regular proper names.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, but those names are all still dependent on the referent. If you take away the referent (and by extension, the context), what inherent meaning does any proper name have beyond etymological? A small subset of names do have actual dictionary (‘literal’) meanings (_Paris_ = fashion, _[friend of] Dorothy_ = gay man, _John Hancock_ = signature, etc.), but those are properties of those particular names, not of ‘names’ as such.

Comment: Right, there's contextual/pragmatic meaning for names, rather than semantic meaning (other than a few that still have extant meaning in English.)